# $facebook->getUser() returns 0 only on mobile network

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I know this question have been asked many-times now, but this is not a duplicate !
I have a weird issue, I am using Nextend Facebook connect plugin for WordPress, and everything works fine but there is one thing that I can't figure out, and I did read **ALL** the previews questions retread to this topic.

The following code returns 0 but only on few mobile deceives :

```
$facebook->getUser();
```

The really weird thing is that if I connect the  mobile to the home WIFI its works fine, as soon as I connected the mobile network its stops from working, So you would say its something with your phone network right ? Well.. I created a hot spot on my phone and connected with my PC to mobile network, guess what ? Its working just fine on PC !

How can this be ?

1. Mobile network on the mobile device the function returns 0.
2. Mobile network on the PC the functions works just fine.
3. WIFI network on the mobile device the functions work fine.
4. WIFI network on the PC the also works fine

Any Ideas why this happens ? I have been trying to figure this out for days now and with no luck, Please any advice would be grate.

**EDIT:** after checking it up once again seems that the mobile network is the problem because its not working on the PC using this network, any ideas ?

Comment: I bet you might be able to see something interesting in the Chrome, Firefox, Safari networking tools when making these requests from your computer, using your phone's internet. I would try and take a look there to see if you're getting HTTP Statuses other than 200 first. Maybe post here what you found?

Comment: I don't sure what was the problem because I made few changes and it works fine now, thank you for your response.